# Android application returns to main activity instead of exiting

Tags: android, exit, exit-code, exit-handler

I created an exit screen for an android application - when the user clicks exit, it is supposed to show the exit screen for 2sec then close the app. This works in android 10 & pixel emulator, but when run on a real device the app comes back to the home screen after exit is clicked and the app closes.

//main activity code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        showExitDialog();
    }
}


private void showExitDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                R.layout.dialog_exit,
                (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutDialogContainer)
        );
        builder.setView(view);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        view.findViewById(R.id.mbtnYes).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LastActivity.class));
                finish();
                onSplashFinished();
            }
        });

        view.findViewById(R.id.mbtnNo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(alertDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        }
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

//last activity code

```
public static final String TAG = "ActivitySplash";
CountDownTimer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last);

    prf = new PrefManager(this);
    developers = findViewById(R.id.developers);
    onSplashFinished();
}


private void onSplashFinished() {
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // If you want to modify a view in your Activity
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initCheck();
}

private void initCheck() {
    if (prf.loadNightModeState()==true){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
}
```